# Why is this for loop getting ignored?

Tags: c, for-loop

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong but the for loop is not initializing
The code just goes immediately to displaying the printfs. That have no values in them since the for loop didn't activate

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define PAUSE system("Pause")

main() {
    // INITALIZE VARIABLES 
    int number = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int odd = 0;
    int even = 0;
    int totalNum = 0;
    int tempNum = 0;
    int count;

    printf("Enter a number between 2 and 25\n");
    scanf("%i", &number);

    do{
        if (number < 2 || number > 25)
            printf("That was an invalid number please try again\n");
            scanf("%i", &number);
    } while (number < 2 || number > 25);

    printf("Enter how many numbers you want to input\n");
    scanf("%i", &count);

    for (i = 1; i == count; ++i){
        printf("input numbers\n");
        scanf("%i", &tempNum);
        if (tempNum % 2 == 0)
            even++;
        else
            odd++;
        totalNum = totalNum + tempNum;
    } // END FOR LOOP

    // DISPLAY OUTPUT
    printf("You entered %i numbers\n", count);
    printf("The sum of the %i numbers is %i\n", count, totalNum);
    printf("The average of the %i numbers is %i\n", count, totalNum / count);
    printf("You entered %i odd numbers and %i even numbers\n", odd, even);

    PAUSE;
} // END MAIN
```

Comment: The answers do not give the fix, `i == count` --> `i <= count` voting to close because of a simple typo.

Comment: The normal idiom to repeat a loop `n` times is `for (i = 0; i < n; i++)`. Get used to counting from 0, it's common in programming.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop will only execute at best once, when `count == 1`  as you initialize `i` to `1`.

If you enter a `1` for count,

```
   printf("Enter how many numbers you want to input\n");
   scanf("%i", &count);
```

the loop will run exactly once, until `i` increments to 2

You probably want:

```
for (i = 1; i <= count; ++i){
```

Comment: please see my comment.

Comment: @WeatherVane I added the fix right before your down vote

Comment: No your fix `i < count` will fail.

Comment: @WeatherVane Once again, I just updated it

Answer (score 1):

```
do{
    if (number < 2 || number > 25)
        printf("That was an invalid number please try again\n");
        scanf("%i", &number);
} while (number < 2 || number > 25);
```

it should be...

```
do{
    if (number < 2 || number > 25){
        printf("That was an invalid number please try again\n");
        scanf("%i", &number);
    }
} while (number < 2 || number > 25);
```

else it asks always another number

Comment: Good catch, it would be better to have a `while(number < 2 || number > 25) {` loop.

Answer (score 0):

`i = 1`, so `i == count;` gives `false` therefore the loop is ignored.

Comment: oh thank you I changed the comparison operators and it works

Comment: @PastelitosSlim You're welcome. Don't forget to choose your best answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

A for loop in C works like this:

```
for ( variable initialization; condition; variable update ) {
    /* Do something... */
}
```

The loop will execute for as long as **condition** is **true**. So, when you do:

```
for (i = 1; i == count; ++i)
```

The loop will execute for as long as **i == count** is true. So, unless **count** holds **1** when this line is executed, the loop will never run.

As others pointed out, you probably want this:

```
for (i = 1; i <= count; ++i)
```

So your loop will run for all values of **i**, until it reaches **count**.

As a side note i should point out that the usual way to write for loops in C is something like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
```

We start with **i = 0** because C arrays are zero-based, so the Nth element of an array has index **n-1**

Answer (score 0):

You were so close. In addition to fixing your loop test clause `for (i = 1; i <= count; i++)`, I would suggest using `" %d"` for your *format specifier*. Your `do` loop need only be a `while` loop to avoid printing your `invalid number` message every time.

Additionally, While not an error, the standard coding style for C avoids `caMelCase` variables in favor of all *lower-case*. See e.g. [**NASA - C Style Guide, 1994**](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/dts/pm/Papers/nasa-c-style.pdf).

With those changes, (and changing your *odd/even* check to a simple `&`) you could write your code as follows.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
// #define PAUSE system("Pause")

int main (void)
{
    int number, i, odd, even, totalnum, tempnum, count;
    number = i = odd = even = totalnum = tempnum = count = 0;

    printf ("enter a number between 2 and 25: ");
    scanf (" %d", &number);

    while (number < 2 || number > 25) {
        printf ("invalid number, again (between 2 and 25): ");
        scanf (" %d", &number);
    }

    printf ("numbers to input: ");
    scanf (" %d", &count);

    for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
        printf ("input number %2d: ", i);
        scanf (" %d", &tempnum);
        if ((tempnum & 1) == 0)
            even++;
        else
            odd++;
        totalnum = totalnum + tempnum;
    }

    printf ("You entered %d numbers\n", count);
    printf ("The sum of the %d numbers is %d\n",
            count, totalnum);
    printf ("The average of the %d numbers is %d\n",
            count, totalnum / count);
    printf ("You entered %d odd numbers and %d even numbers\n",
            odd, even);

//     PAUSE;
    return 0;
}
```

**note:** `main` is type `int` (e.g. `int main (int argc, char **argv)` or simply `int main (void)` to indicate no arguments taken). Since it is type `int` it will `return` a value to the shell. While historic implementations may have allowed `void main` that is no longer the case for portable code.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ /bin/forskipped
enter a number between 2 and 25: 4
numbers to input: 4
input number  1: 1
input number  2: 2
input number  3: 3
input number  4: 4
You entered 4 numbers
The sum of the 4 numbers is 10
The average of the 4 numbers is 2
You entered 2 odd numbers and 2 even numbers
```

Look it over and let me know if you have any questions.